# Let's promote our community!

Tags: discussion, promotion

This year's Community Promotion Ads have started on all the graduated sites. This is a great chance to promote our site on the other sites. Of course this doesn't mean we should spam each and every SE site with ads for Movies & TV either, but at least the ones with a related scope are worth a try.

And when we're talking about sites with related scopes, of course the first adress is [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) and thus I've already [proposed an ad for our site there](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5328/23386), as done in the previous years, too. I'm not sure which other sites might be related enough to warrant an ad for our site, Video Production is still in beta, but maybe [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) and [Anime & Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/) might be an idea?

So what can we do? First and foremost, **be sure to vote for the Community Promotion Ads of our site on the other sites' metas** if you like them and feel they're appropriate. But also **feel free to propose ads on other SE sites where you deem Movies & TV relevant**. But be sure to not just slam an M&TV sticker onto it but try to adjust it to the scope of the specific site a bit (e.g. maybe referencing a well-know game-adaptation in the ad for Arqade or something similar).

Any proposals you make might be shared in an answer to this "question" here, like any other related ideas you want to share. Or you might want to just post it as an answer here in order for our community to vote for it before actually proposing it to the other site.

Comment: I'm starting a movie review blog with a friend of mine. I don't expect much traffic, but I'll link to M&TV SE when we get it going.

Comment: @BenPlont Great, and be sure to in turn inform us about your blog once it's on the air.

Answer (score 11):

I updated our ad image for [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) to the new graduated design using our specific color palette and icons and to the new ad dimensions of 300x250 (or rather 600x500 for high-DPI displays). I made a few changes to the ad, keeping the general idea but moving to a more streamlined design.

[image]

We proposed it on the [corresponding ad proposal thread for 2019](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12298/23386).

Answer (score 7):

Since [Anime & Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/) just graduated, they also have Community Promotion Ads now. I tried to come up with an ad specific for them and settled for concentrating on the animation aspect, yet of course the kind of animation you can't ask about there.

[image]

We proposed it on the [corresponding ad proposal thread for 2019](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4220/2176).

Answer (score 6):

I've been a member here for almost two years. I'm really excited about our upcoming graduation.

I have started a [movie review blog](https://benandjoeatthemovies.wordpress.com) with a friend of mine. I have added a page and a link back to Movies & TV SE as well as a couple of links to actual questions (of course one had to be a question from @Napolean Wilson). I have also added a blurb that I lifted from the tour page.

We probably won't be generating much traffic, but I still want to do what I can to promote this community.

edit: please forgive the plug for tour blog. It doesn't generate any money, and mostly I wanted to post about it to share what I'm doing to promote M&TV.

Answer (score 5):

I made a Community Promotion Ad for [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), concentrating on various famous film adaptations of video games or films strongly inspired/related to video games:

[image]

We proposed this on the [corresponding ad proposal thread for 2019](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13244/112299).

Comment: This is really cool!

Comment: If only adaptations of video games weren't so crappy, generally speaking :D